# HUDI Spark Kryo. Task serialization failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo

Tags: apache-spark, kryo, apache-hudi

I use spark-shell to run hudi,  and the following are the configuration arguments:

```bash
spark-shell --packages org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12:0.12.0 --conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' --conf 'spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog' --conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension' --conf 'spark.kryo.registrator=org.apache.spark.HoodieSparkKryoRegistrar'
```

In spark-shell, I import the following libraries and run a test case:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode._
import org.apache.hudi.DataSourceWriteOptions._
import org.apache.hudi.config.HoodieWriteConfig._
spark.range(1).write.format("org.apache.hudi").option(TABLE_NAME, "hudi_tab01").option(PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "id").option(RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "id").mode(Overwrite).save("/tmp/hudi_tab01")
```

Then the following error occurred:

```bash
ERROR TorrentBroadcast: Store broadcast broadcast_0 fail, remove all pieces of the broadcast
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:183)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
```

Provided that I did not compile the hudi source code with Maven and only downloaded the hudi dependency package in the spark-shell.
Is the error related to a jar dependency package? Is it related to the HUDI_CONF_DIR or hudi-defaults. conf file? If so, how should I configure it? Have any friends encountered this error and found a solution.

I would greatly appreciate it if it could be resolved!
Thanks!

Comment: I accidentally remove that configuration and it worked. Remove --conf 'spark.kryo.registrator=org.apache.spark.HoodieSparkKryoRegistrar', that class is only available in later release. Check config in this doc for 0.12.3 version -

The same question: https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/9974